# Baby Rudin Ex. 1.6, part b

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that $b^{r+s}=b^rb^s$ if $r$ and $s$ are rational.

The model solution provided by Cooke basically solves this "by the laws of exponents for integer exponents", i.e. the statement is true if $r,s$ were integers (he does not prove this).

Problem is, I cannot find an axiom or a proof for integer exponents in the first chapter. It's kind of a letdown to find that the model solution invokes some lemma or theorem that is not in the book...Something I'm missing here? I can post Cooke's solution here in entirety if it is allowed.

Edit: The solution requires proving:
$b^{mw+vn}=b^{mw}b^{vn}$, where $m,w,v,n$ are integers. Cooke states that this is proven "by the laws of exponents for integer exponents". This is not in the book, am I wrong?

Comment: I believe that all that is needed is proving Ex 1.6 part a -- for $r=m/n=p/q$, $b^{m/n}=b^{p/q}$ allowing you to define $b^r:=\sqrt[n]{m}$.

Comment: For a more detailed account: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws/Product_of_Powers

Then to explain the exponent of sum:
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_of_Sum/Real_Numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are right. In fact, it appears that even the definition of $b^n$ (for real $b$ and integer $n$) is missing. Fortunately, this is not too hard to remedy. For nonnegative integers $n$, define $b^n$ inductively by $b^0=1$ and $b^{n+1} = bb^n$, and define $b^{-n}=1/b^n$. Then to prove the identity $b^{r+s}=b^rb^s$ for nonnegative integers $r$, $s$, just use induction, say, on $s$. This identity can then be extended to all integers $r$ and $s$ by separately considering the possible sign combinations of $r$ and $s$.